# I am working with fibonacci numbers, where the "n" for the n-th number is in 5-6 digits. how can i reduce the time taken for execution?

Tags: java

In this specific problem, what I had to do is find the Fibonacci numbers, square them, and then find the sum of those squared numbers. Which was fine up until the range limit of the long data type.

Here's what I've got till now... I switched to BigInteger after noticing that the range of long couldn't handle the large Fibonacci numbers, and that did the trick but increased the time complexity exponentially. And since I needed to retain most of the numbers, I needed to make an array for the numbers to store them.

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;
public class FibonacciSumSquares {
    private static BigInteger getFibonacciSumSquares(int n) {

        if (n <= 1)
            return BigInteger.valueOf(n);

        BigInteger sum = BigInteger.valueOf(0);
        BigInteger a[] = new BigInteger[n];
        a[0] = a[1] = BigInteger.ONE;
        for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
            a[i] = a[i - 1].add(a[i - 2]);
            a[i] = a[i].pow(2);
            sum = sum.add(a[i]);
        }
        return sum;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int n = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.println(getFibonacciSumSquares(n));
    }
}
```

After accepting the first answer I ran some stress tests on the code snippet and the correction that was needed was an "=" sign in the code. hope that helps. For more details please refer to the answer's comments.

Comment: Regarding your question: Of course, BigInteger allows you for really large numbers. But of course, any numerical operation on BigInteger objects is much more expensive compared to using the long primitive type for example. So: if you really want performance and LARGE numbers, beyond the limitations of long ... then you could start with long, and when reaching its limitations, switch to BigInteger for example.

Comment: Note you are obstructing your array of Fibonacci numbers by overwriting every ith value with its square.

Comment: You could also ditch the array and only retain the last 2 values, but that would be an improvement more in the spatial complexity.

Comment: as far as the review of my post goes, thanks I'll try and do that. @GhostCat

Comment: and thanks for pointing out the long range one, really slipped my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BigInteger runs more slower than java primitive types, so use primitive in long range.
here is my code and result:

```
public class FibonacciSumSquares {
private static BigInteger getFibonacciSumSquares(int n) {
    if (n <= 1)
        return BigInteger.valueOf(n);
    BigInteger sum = BigInteger.ZERO;
    long last = 1, lastTwo = 1, current = 0;
    BigInteger lastBigInteger = BigInteger.ONE;
    BigInteger lastTwoBigInteger = BigInteger.ONE;
    BigInteger currentBigInteger;
    boolean isUsePrimary = true;

    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        if (isUsePrimary) {
            current = last + lastTwo;
            current = current * current;
            if (current > (last + lastTwo)) {
                lastTwo = last;
                last = current;
                sum = sum.add(BigInteger.valueOf(current));
            } else {
                isUsePrimary = false;
                lastTwoBigInteger = BigInteger.valueOf(lastTwo);
                lastBigInteger = BigInteger.valueOf(last);
                currentBigInteger = lastBigInteger.add(lastTwoBigInteger);
                currentBigInteger = currentBigInteger.pow(2);

                sum = sum.add(currentBigInteger);
            }
        } else {
            currentBigInteger = lastBigInteger.add(lastTwoBigInteger);
            currentBigInteger = currentBigInteger.pow(2);
            sum = sum.add(currentBigInteger);
        }
    }
    return sum;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(getFibonacciSumSquares(10000));
    System.out.println("used time(ms): " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
    /**
     * On: MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014)
     *
     * n = 10000
     * 811453295998950457153326378602357232029212
     * used time(ms): 24
     *
     * n = 20000
     * 1623556274380606238932066737816445867589212
     * used time(ms): 32
     *
     * n = 999999
     * 81209566945485034687670444066761210743605656
     * used time(ms): 368
     */
}
```

}

Comment: The work of 2nd if statement is to tackle the range of the long data type right?

Comment: I did some stress testing for your code (the random class ranging from 0 to 6000) and I'd like to tell you that the snippet works perfectly but for the value "2" since the for loop overlooks it particularly. so I'd like to suggest you add a "=" sign in the for loop in the condition "i<n " upgrading it to "i<=n".

Comment: so I'd like to suggest you add a "=" sign in the for loop in the condition "i<n " upgrading it to "i<=n"

eh... i <= n